# How do I parse a single-value JSON response from an API?

Tags: json, swift

I'm making a call to the url: https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/price (with a token).

It returns a single float value: 384.73. That's it. But, it is still encoded, and my loadRequest depends on having a decodable struct. Here, since there is no real JSON to create the struct for, I can't conform to this protocol. So, how do I decode a single value JSON response? When I print the response, it prints: "5150 bytes". Here's the function.

```
    func getPrice(stock: String, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        urlComponents.path = "/stable/stock/\(stock)/book"
        let request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
        NetworkManager().loadRequest(request: request) { (data) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            print(data)
            completion(data)
        }
    }
```

I feel a bit silly asking this, but I can't figure it out. Cheers.

Comment: The link is not useful. `400 Bad Request`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes, I have a private key with the request. The request is returning the correct data, I just can't decode it.

Comment: What is the response ? `"384.73"` it is not 5150 bytes. Convert your data to string g and print it. Then edit your question and post the result. `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")`

Comment: You said that you're calling `../price` ([docs](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#price-only)), but your sample code actually calls `../book` ([docs](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#book)). This is the reason for 5150 bytes vs `384.73`. It's not a valid JSON (not an array/object), but you can get the number via `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)` (`.allowFragments` allows you to get `NSNumber` from just `"384.73"`).

Comment: _... from just `"384.73"`_ should actually be `384.73` (like `let data = "384.73".data(using: .utf8)!`).